# Use of ArrayUtils.removeElement() created another array?

Tags: java

I have a doubt with array basics.
Array by default is a mutable object and in theory I can't remove elements.
The doubt is if I use `ArrayUtils.removeElement()` I'll create another array in memory?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Array *elements* are mutable, the *size* is not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will create another array in memory:

> This method returns a new array with the same elements of the input array except the first occurrence of the specified element.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#removeElement(boolean[], boolean)